# How to exclude a word during replaceAll function in java

Tags: java, replaceall

I have a situation where I need to remove all the A-Z characters in a file. I could do this by using replaceAll method in java but at the same time I want to exclude few words from getting replaced.

For example:

```
str = str.replaceAll("|(?i)A|(?i)B|(?i)C|(?i)D|(?i)E|(?i)F|(?i)G|(?i)H|(?i)I|(?i)J|(?i)K|(?i)L|(?i)M|(?i)N|(?i)O|(?i)P|(?i)Q|(?i)U|(?i)R|(?i)S|(?i)T|(?i)W|(?i)X|(?i)Y|(?i)Z|,"");
```

> U0000 - *** This should be excluded while applying replace all logic
>
> ---
>
> ABCD0000

Output:

> 0000
>
> 0000

Any assistance?

Comment: it would be helpful if you could post your code including where you are doing your output

Comment: why not just `replaceAll("[A-Za-z]", "")`?

Comment: Can you post **expected output** versus your current actual output. What sort of words are you trying to exclude and what is special about them?

Answer (score 1):

Try this way:

```
//split the string with your special string
String[] strs = str.split("U0000");
//Iterate through this array and do your "replaceAll" for each string element.
...
//Join the array elements to form your final string
str = String.join("U0000", strs);
```

Here's a small example that shows how to replace all alphabets but "U" if it is succeded by 4 zeroes.

```
String str = "a3(BcU0000gs23";
String[] strs = str.split("U0000");
str = Arrays.stream(strs).map(e -> e.replaceAll("[a-zA-Z]", "")).collect(Collectors.joining("U0000"));
System.out.println(str);
```